# Is there a need to put a space after colon in CSS declaration?

Tags: css

I am really bad in CSS,
I often see people using colon + space :-

```
a {color: red;}  /* colon followed by space */
a {color:red;}   /* instead of this */
```

Both still does the same (at least browser still renders it the same).
So, is this just a code formatting preference?
(Does it carry any hidden meaning ?)

Comment: no hidden meaning.. just style

Comment: @DMoses, comments that are answers are just noise.  (they should be answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's for readability. You can minify CSS to compress it for production servers, using tools such as [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/css.html).

Comment: agreed, i think the google page speed always has something like this.

Answer (score 6):

It is not necessary, it's just a readability preference.

Comment: If you are removing whitespace from your CSS by hand because of performance you are doing something wrong.  (i.e.  keyboardP's minifying suggestion is the way to go)

Answer (score 4):

It's there for nothing more than just readability for the person who coded it.
Here's a good roundup of formatting your stylesheets; keep in mind, they all do the same thing, it's just a matter of personal preference:

http://css-tricks.com/3058-different-ways-to-format-css/